Are wss:// websocket server URLs supported by Micronaut @ClientWebSocket?
Has anyone used a wss:// (secure) URL with a Micronaut websocket client?  According to the docs it seems like it should work but I always get a "Error opening WebSocket client session: Abnormal Closure" error on connect with no further error messages.  The code works fine with an insecure ws:// websocket server.
@MicronautTest
class WssTestTest {
    @Inject
    WebSocketClient webSocketClient;

    @ClientWebSocket
    public static abstract class TestWebSocketClient implements AutoCloseable {
        @OnMessage
        void onMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("message = " + message);
        }

        public abstract void send(@NonNull String message);
    }

    @Test
    void testItWorks() {
        String url = "wss://echo.websocket.org/";
        Publisher<TestWebSocketClient> clientPublisher = webSocketClient.connect(TestWebSocketClient.class,  url);
        TestWebSocketClient client = Flux.from(clientPublisher).blockFirst();
        client.send("Hello");
    }
}


I reported this bug to micronaut-core github repository.
You can work around it for now by setting micronaut.http.client.alpn-modes=http/1.1
